# What is an elegant way to try catch properties in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring, try-catch

What's an elegant way to refactor this code?

Say, I have the following object

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public SomeInnerObject1 Cat { get; set; }
    public SomeInnerObject2 Dog { get; set; }

    public class SomeInnerObject1
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string AgeAsString
        {
            get
            {
                if(Age < 0 )
                    throw new Exception();

                return Age.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeInnerObject2
    {
        public string BirthDayString { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDay { get { return DateTime.Parse(BirthDayString); } }
    }
}
```

And say, I have to set a few textboxes's values that I need to set

```
var obj = new SomeObject
          {
              Cat = new SomeObject.SomeInnerObject1 {Age = -1},
              Dog = null
          };

//These will pass but it looks ugly
try
{
    textbox1.Text = obj.Dog.BirthDay.Month.ToString();
}
catch{ }

try
{
    textbox2.Text = obj.Cat.AgeAsString;
}
catch { }

//These will fail
textbox1.Text = obj.Dog.BirthDay.Month.ToString();
textbox2.Text = obj.Cat.AgeAsString;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Chi

Comment: Why do those functions fail? Does obj/dog/birthday or month not exists?

Comment: @PoweRoy - Presumably he would need to check for `null` reference at each object, which would get really ugly. So he's just wrapped the access with `try..catch` to avoid the validation.

Comment: I have added the update. It's because sometimes Birthday can be null or an invalid string. And SomeInnerObject1 can also throw as well.

Comment: @Yuck - Not only that, but Birthday parsing can fail if you get birthday to something like "Foo" :(. So I need to handle that case as well.

Comment: Don't use exceptions as a means of validation.  Use if/else blocks.

Comment: @Inuyasha - That's another way of doing it, but it's just as messy as try catching. Ideally, I would want some kind of one-liner to set my textboxes and hide all the validations somewhere else.

Comment: This smells like Aspect Oriented Programming to me (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: The whole thing is a mass of .NET guideline violations. Nested types should not be public. Property getters should never throw exceptions. Exceptions should not be used as mainline control flow. I would refactor this by starting over and writing something that conforms to the frameworks guidelines.

Comment: Your classes are badly designed. If you improve their design the need for these `catch` clauses will most likely disappear.

Comment: @Chi Chan, its "just as messy", but that isn't the point.  You shouldn't use exceptions for application logic.  They are much slower than if blocks.  It is Bad Design.

Comment: Even for an example `int Int;` and `string String;` are bad and confusing names.

Comment: @Henk - Thanks, what was I thinking! I have fixed the confusing names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I really don't care what happens for a particular line of code, I do something like this:

```
ExecuteIgnoringExceptions(() => textBox.Text = Some.Possibly.Bad.Value);

void ExecuteIgnoringExceptions(Action a) 
{
    try
    {
        a.Invoke();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I typically do but in a few cases I use invoke for readability (which is, of course, in the eye of the beholder). But I'm still fairly new to C# so is there a particular reason I shouldn't use invoke?

Comment: Invoke calls the method via reflection. Calling it directly removes reflection out of the picture. Much faster :) Edit: Actually, I confused myself. They are the same. Got confused with `MethodInfo`.

Comment: I don't think `Invoke` uses reflection. Directly calling a delegate is just syntactic sugar over `Invoke`

Answer (score 2):

Try these extension methods; they will perform the null-checking (via try-catch) and return a default value (which you can specify if you don't want the .NET default):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a null-safe member accessor that will return either the result of the lambda or the specified default value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The type of the in.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The type of the out.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
    /// <param name="projection">A lambda specifying the value to produce.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value to use if the projection or any parent is null.</param>
    /// <returns>the result of the lambda, or the specified default value if any reference in the lambda is null.</returns>
    public static TOut ValueOrDefault<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> projection, TOut defaultValue)
        where TOut : class
    {
        try
        {
            return projection(input) ?? defaultValue;
        }
        //Catches attempts to access a child of a null object
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        //Catches attempts to access the value of a null Nullable<T>
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a null-safe member accessor that will return either the result of the lambda or the default value for the type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The type of the in.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The type of the out.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
    /// <param name="projection">A lambda specifying the value to produce.</param>
    /// <returns>the result of the lambda, or default(TOut) if any reference in the lambda is null.</returns>
    public static TOut ValueOrDefault<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> projection)
        where TOut : class
    {
        return input.ValueOrDefault(projection, default(TOut));
    }
```

Usage:

```
//no try-catch needed
textbox1.Text = obj.ValueOrDefault(o=>o.Dog.BirthDay.Month.ToString(), String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by moving the `Int` check from the get to the set property. If it isn't supposed to be less than 0, then don't let it get set to less than 0. For the date, use a `TryParse` method in the setter to make it exception safe. Then make sure that use a private setter in the BirthDay property.

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public SomeInnerObject1 Cat { get; set; }
    public SomeInnerObject2 Dog { get; set; }

    public class SomeInnerObject1
    {
        private int _Int = 0;
        public int Int {
            get
            {
                return _Int;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value < 0) 
                    throw new Exception("Int must be greater than or equal to 0.");
                else
                    _Int = value;
            }
       }

        public string String
        {
            get
            {
                return Int.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeInnerObject2
    {
        private string _BirthDayString = "";
        public string BirthDayString
        {
            get
            {
                return _BirthDayString;
            }
            set
            {
                DateTime newDate;
                if(DateTime.TryParse(value, newDate))
                    BirthDay = newDate;
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException("Birthday string must be a properly formatted date.");
            }
        }

        private DateTime _BirthDay = DateTime.MinValue;
        public DateTime BirthDay
        {
            get 
            {
                return _BirthDay;
            }
            private set
            {
                _BirthDay = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main point being that values should be validated on the way in rather than on the way out.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I agree, but in my usage the value of the object is out of my control. I am deserializing a JSON object returned from some Facebook service that may or may not contain an object/value. I want to allow nulls in my POCO, and handle the cases later.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be able to store invalid birthday strings, then I'd make `BirthDay` a normal `DateTime?` or `DateTime` property. And then parse the input value and assign the result of the parsing to the property.

If you really need to store the string you could rewrite the birthday case to:

```
public DateTime? BirthDay
{
  get
  {
    DateTime result;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(BirthDayString,out result))
      return result;
    else
      return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option - Don't throw the base Exception class in your property assignments, and then wrap the assignments in a method that can provide a default value.

Something quick and dirty like:

```
//assignment will throw
var x = SafeAssign(()=>((string)(null)).ToString(),"test");

T SafeAssign<T>(Func<T> input, T defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        return input();
    }
    catch //todo - catch better exceptions
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try really hard to avoid throwing exceptions from property getters. The Framework Design Guidelines say:

> AVOID throwing exceptions from
>   property getters. Property getters
>   should be simple operations and should
>   not have preconditions. If a getter
>   can throw an exception, it should
>   probably be redesigned to be a method.
>   Note that this rule does not apply to
>   indexers, where we do expect
>   exceptions as a result of validating
>   the arguments. Note that this
>   guideline only applies to property
>   getters. It is OK to throw an
>   exception in a property setter.

Developers have grown accustomed to being able to call property getters safely almost all of the time. They do not want a getter that performs complex computations or requires a lot of CPU time to complete. And they certainly would prefer that they not throw exceptions. For most part the BCL and everyone else follow this guideline and it is advisable that you do as well.